How does the assassin leave Hungary with a fake passport?
In Ep 6, the Jackal is trapped in Hungary and he asks his wife for help, who brings his skin-like masks along with other stuff in a bag.
The Jackal puts on his skin-like mask and dress like an old man, leaves Hungary for Estonia in a wheelchair.
What I finds illogical is:

The Jackal arrives in Hungary undisguised, his passport photo must have matched his youngthful look and the Hungarian custom must have recorded his entry in their database.
How does Jackal leaves Hungary as an old man, his passport photo must have matched his old look and the second passport will not have a record of entry in the Hungarian custom data base. They will have caught him at the border.

How does it work out for him?

If he's masquerading as a Hungarian, his passport wouldn't show him entering Hungary.

And even if he isn't, both Estonia and Hungary are in the Schengen Area, so there are no immigration or border controls between them.


Hungarian custom must have recorded his entry in their database.

Firstly, note it's not Customs (which deal with importation of goods) but Immigration or Border Security.
However, there is no database. Instead, passports are stamped on entry and exit.

If you’re a visitor, border guards will look at your entry and exit stamps to check you have not overstayed the 90-day visa-free limit for the Schengen area.
source

So, partly you have a point but the issue would be a potentially missing entry stamp on the new (old man) passport.

If your passport is missing a stamp, show evidence of when and where you entered or left the Schengen area (for example, boarding passes or tickets) and ask the border guards to add the date and location in your passport.

However in this instance, it's more likely that a man as adaptable and resourceful as the Jackal simply faked the entry stamp in his new passport.
In universe, this is simply glossed over to keep the plot moving.

While most of your answer is correct, it is also mostly irrelevant: Estonia and Hungary are both within the Schengen Area, so there are no immigration and border controls between them. In episodes 1–7 so far, we have never seen the Jackal enter or leave the Schengen Area, so he would never have passed immigration.

As of December, 21st 2007, Estonia and Hungary are both members of the Schengen Area. The Schengen Area is a multi-lateral treaty between 29 European countries that abolish regular, permanent immigration and border controls between them.
In other words, there are no borders inside the Schengen Area. As of episode 7 of the show, we have only ever seen the Jackal travel between countries within the Schengen Area (Estonia, France, Germany, Hungary, Spain, Sweden), so he would never have come across immigration or border security.
Based on the information we have been given so far, the only time the Jackal would ever have passed immigration was when he first entered the Schengen Area after leaving Afghanistan.
He only needed to pass the security check at the airport (and fulfill the passenger identification requirements of the airline, of course), but they didn't care about an old man in a wheelchair – they were looking for a much younger man.
